# Topology Exercise

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am attempting to solve the following exercise.

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\psi: \mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow
>  \mathcal{P}(X)$ defined by: If $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ then $\psi(A)$
>   equals the closure of the interior of $A$. Show that $\psi^2=\psi$.

**My thoughts:** We want to show that $\psi^{2}=\psi\circ\psi=\psi$.

\begin{array}{ccccc}
\mathcal{P}(X) & \overset{\psi}{\rightarrow} & \mathcal{P}(X) & \overset{\psi}{\rightarrow} & \mathcal{P}(X)\\
A & \mapsto & \overline{\text{int}(A)} & \mapsto & \overline{\text{int}(\overline{\text{int}(A)})}
\end{array}

It suffices to show that $\overline{\text{int}(A)}=\overline{\text{int}(\overline{\text{int}(A)})}$.

**My questions:** My only question is if my reasoning is sound, i.e., if I identified correctly what I need to prove. I get the feeling that the statement of the exercise is too "complicated" for what it comes down to.

**Note:** I know how to prove the equality above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you identified correctly what needs to be proved.